# How to make sinatra process requests simultaneously?

Tags: sinatra

I have simple [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) script

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'sinatra'  

get '/' do
  %x[sleep.bat] #dos batch file that waits for 10sec
end
```

which simulates my real sintra script that calls ant script. The ant run can finish in an hour or so. **I want to use my sinatra application while the ant run is running.** But sinatra waits till the ant run finishes. Then it processes whatever requests I made meanwhile.

I use

- Windows XP SP3
- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
- sinatra (1.2.6, 1.0)
- and one rb file

Comment: Do you need to return the results from your call to your ants script?

Comment: I need to get results from the ant script. Not sure what you meant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a process that runs for an hour is really an entirely different situation, Rack applications are typically run with multiple app servers.  This will allow you to make additional requests while your long-running call is busy.

You can run a Rack application under any of the typical ruby app servers.  Passenger, Unicorn or Thin could all address your needs in this respect.

Comment: Any chance to elaborate more on that? I have no idea what you are talking about :-)

Comment: Yeah... give me a few minutes.  Gotta put the kids down.  :-)

Comment: Thank you. My sinatra application starts web automation testing. Only one ant run can be started at a time. What I want to be able 1) make sure that user cannot start new test if one is already running 2) browse test result - that is my initial question. How to make it work so I can browse results while test is being executed. At present I can do only either of them.

Comment: First thing to try would be to run two instances of your Sinatra application.  Chances are, you could let the long-running request just run and still access the other functions on the other Sinatra instance.

Comment: I thought that is not possible or advised as both instances will listen to the same port ...

Comment: 'Tis true.  Typically you'll setup a web server in front of multiple app servers.  So you might have app servers listening on 3000, 3001, 3002, etc... and then a web server listening on port 80 distributing requests to the app servers.  Nginx is one popular web server that works well in this kind of configuration.

Comment: Can I somehow use existing sinatra code? What if I run three instances of sintra. One as web server and the other two as application server? Is that possible?

Comment: You could also just use something like [AsyncSinatra](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra). But you'd have to learn a bit about EventMachine and the Reactor Pattern.